# How to make Lookup table in Python showing it in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

I am trying to make a lookup table for image which I load to my program, but I have a problem.

This is what I have been trying, but doesn't work as expected:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2 as cv
top = Tk()
path_example = 'C:/Users/dog.jpg'
imgopen = cv.imread(path_example)
imgopen = cv.cvtColor(imgopen, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
row = imgopen.shape[0]
col = imgopen.shape[1]
Lookup_table_values = [0] * 256
for i in range(0, row):
    for j in range(0, col):
        Lookup_table_values[imgopen[i, j]] += 1

x1 = [i for i in range (32)]
x2 = [i for i in range (32, 64)]
x3 = [i for i in range (64, 96)]
x4 = [i for i in range (96, 128)]
x5 = [i for i in range (128, 160)]
x6 = [i for i in range (160, 192)]
x7 = [i for i in range (192, 224)]
x8 = [i for i in range (224, 256)]
n = 32
y = [Lookup_table_values[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(Lookup_table_values), n)]
t = [(x1), (x2), (x3), (x4), (x5), (x6), (x7), (x8), (y)]
for x in range(len(t)):
    for y in range(len(t[x])):
        w = Text(top, width=4, height=2)
        w.grid(row=x, column=y)
        w.insert('end', t[x][y])

top.mainloop()
```

at least I made it show, but how to have values from lookup table in the right index?[image]

Comment: first of don't use `len` to access values from an iterable, use `for value in iterable`, if you need the index too then use `for index, value in enumerate(iterable)` and I still don't understand what is your issue? what is the lookup table? what images? please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have edited my code and made it reproducible. Lookup table is where information about image is stored. About the level of brightness and how many pixels are on a specific level.

Comment: you never iterate over the look up value table in a way that would place those values in the table, you literally iterate over the ranges, you need to iterate over `Lookup_table_values` and place those values in their according row and column, you are iterating over a list that contains lists of ranges